# Stop Qt QGraphicsView from scrolling on re-size

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, horizontal-scrolling, qgraphicsview

I have two QGraphicsView that are of equal width, one ontop the other in a Vertical Layout.

When I re-size my application window, the QGraphicsView on the bottom does what I expect, it remains at the exact position it started at, however the top view begins to move the scene to the right exposing coordinates that are below x=0(essentially blank padding on the left edge of the View), which I do not want, I need both to behave the same because they correspond to each other.

I must have missed something, because should these views behave exactly the same? I need them to align, as the top view has hidden scroll bars and scrolls horizontally by however much the bottom view is scrolled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your [resizeAnchor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#resizeAnchor-prop) is set to `NoAnchor` and [alignment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop) is `Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop`. You may need to try some other combination to work with your situation.

Comment: Thanks works great. Any chance with helping me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528432/programmatic-qgraphicsview-scrolling-not-updating-properly