# Programmatic QGraphicsView scrolling not updating properly

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, scroll

I have a custom class derived from QGraphicsView that implements a slot call scrollHorizontal(int dx), inside the code is simply

```
void CustomView::scrollHorizontal(int dx){
    scrollContentsBy(dx, 0);
}
```

My problem is, scrolling like this works but doesn't update the scene properly, instead any pixels found on the edge of the view are repeated instead of having a fresh call to the item's `paint()` method.

I've attempted calling `update()` after, but nothing happens. I tried enabling scrolling by dragging and updates work fine! But I need it done programmatically, and since I have the scroll bars hidden things like `horizontalScrollBar()->setValue()` do not scroll the view.

I also tried   :

```
scrollContentsBy(dx, 0);
this->scene()->invalidate(sceneRect());
this->update();
```

update:

```
QPointF center = mapToScene(viewport()->rect().center()); 
centerOn(center.x() - dx, center.y()); 
update();
```

is working, but now my top view is scrolling slower than my bottom view, which is a new problem. They are linked with `signal`s and `slot`s, in the bottom view i have `scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)` overrided to `emit horizontalScroll(dx)`; which is caught by the above `slot` in the top view.

Any ideas why the scrolls happen at different rates? Might it have something to do with the scroll bars being a part of the bottom view effectively making it a "smaller" window?

update 2:

The different scroll rates seems to stem from some rounding happening to give me an integer based "center" using `mapToScene(viewport()->rect().center());` , as you scroll and the slower you scroll the more this error adds up, the faster you scroll the less total error.

Is there a way for me to get around this? I don't see any way to get a floating point center point.

update 3:

So I have this mostly solved, turns out the mapToScene was needed(code I found elsewhere on the web).

I fixed this by storing `QPointF` of FP calculated center of the viewport, now the amount of error when scrolling the two views is unnoticeable.

The final issue is, the views no longer line up when you scroll ANY amount to the right, and then resize the window then scroll again. I assume this has something to do with the logical ordering of when the center point is calculated and when the centering happens.

Right now I use the following code snippet in `QGraphicsScene::ResizeEvent()` and elsewhere that updates the center as needed

```
QRectF viewPort(viewport()->rect());
QPointF rectCenter((viewPort.x() + viewPort.x() + viewPort.width())/2.0, (viewPort.y() + viewPort.y() + viewPort.height())/2.0);

viewCenter = rectCenter;
```

and my `horizontalScroll(int dx)` `slot`

```
void CustomView::horizontalScroll(int dx)
{
    viewCenter.setX(viewCenter.x() - dx);
    centerOn(viewCenter.x(), viewCenter.y());
    update();
}
```

How can I fix the issue when re-sizing the window breaking the alignment of the two views? If any more clarification is needed please just ask, I can try to give skeletons of what I'm referring to if need be.

Update 4:

Rough code Skeleton

```
Class HeaderView:

class HeaderView View : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HeaderView(QWidget * parent = 0);
    HeaderView(QGraphicsScene * scene, QWidget * parent = 0);

private:
    QPointF viewCenter;

protected:
    void resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event );

public slots:
    void horizontalScroll(int);
    void addModel(qreal, qreal, const QString&);

};
```

HeaderView.cpp

```
void HeaderView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    QRectF viewPort(viewport()->rect());
    QPointF rectCenter((viewPort.x() + viewPort.x() + viewPort.width())/2.0, (viewPort.y() + viewPort.y() + viewPort.height())/2.0);

    viewCenter = rectCenter;
}

void HeaderView::horizontalScroll(int dx)
{
    viewCenter.setX(viewCenter.x() - dx);
    centerOn(viewCenter.x(), viewCenter.y());
    update();
}
```

Class EventView:

```
class EventView : public QGraphicsView
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    EventView(QWidget * parent = 0);
    EventView(QGraphicsScene * scene, QWidget * parent = 0);
    QRectF visibleRect();

protected:
     void scrollContentsBy ( int dx, int dy );

signals:
    void horizontalScroll(int);

};
```

EventView.cpp

```
void EventView::scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)
{
    QGraphicsView::scrollContentsBy(dx, dy);

    if(dx != 0){
        emit horizontalScroll(dx);
    }
}
```

Somwhere in Class MainWindow:

```
connect(eventView, SIGNAL(horizontalScroll(int)), headerView, SLOT(horizontalScroll(int));
```

Comment: I'd really like to take a look at a minimal example of code that reproduces this.

Comment: I also think that the best idea is to create a minimal example code. Only those two views with their connection. Can you do this? This will help a lot. Maybe you'll find the solution while doing so, this often happens. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've worked with `QGraphicsView` in Qt 4.6.3 - 4.7.2 and have to argue that you *can* use the respective `QScrollBar` in the following way:

```
//graphics view initialization
QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(parent);
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,widthOfScene,heightOfScene,parent);
graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
graphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
graphicsView->setScene(scene);

//in another method
QScrollBar* yPos=graphicsView->verticalScrollBar();
yPos->setValue((int) newValue);
```

It does not matter if they are hidden or not. They will still respond to `setValue(int)` as long as you have a graphics scene that is larger than the graphics view.

The `QGraphicsView` will also respond to `ensureVisible`, which moves the scrollbars to the appropriate location.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to scollBar.scroll() which mistakenly was a public QWidget function inherited by scroll bar.

Ultimately I ended up syncing the windows with emitting/catching this->horizontalScrollBar()->value() and setValue()

Comment: Great answer! This just saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to call `scrollContentsBy` as explained here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy

I don't know if you can still call the hidden scrollbar to scroll it. If not,  [`translate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#translate) is an option.

Comment: Calling translate(dx, 0) doesn't do anything to the scene.

Comment: Well. It should work. But try centerOn a scene point then. You need to calculate the point yourself.

Comment: void CustomView::horizontalScroll(int dx)
{
    QPointF center = mapToScene(viewport()->rect().center());
    centerOn(center.x() + dx, center.y());
    update();
}
does not work either

Comment: QPointF center = mapToScene(viewport()->rect().center());
    centerOn(center.x() - dx, center.y());
    update();

is working, but now my top view is scrolling slower than my bottom view, which is a new problem.

Comment: If the goal is to track one set of view and scene to another, and the 2 scenes have the same size, I would look into duplicating the view transformation. Whenever the driving view changes, set the driven view to have the same transformation.

Comment: Are you saying QGraphicsView does all of its changes via setTransform() calls on itself?

Comment: Tried it, no calls go to setTransform() on scrolls.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the scroll bars? Hiding them doesn't make them non-existent, and [the documentation says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy) you should use `QScrollBar::setValue` to scroll to a given position.

Another option would be to use [`QGraphicsView::centerOn(QPointF)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) in conjunction with the current center point -- as you've also tried -- but directly calculating the center point within your method (**do not precalculate and store the center point**), by using [`QGraphicsView::mapToScene(int,int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene-5):

```
void CustomView::horizontalScroll(int dx)
{
    QPointF viewCenter = mapToScene(width() / 2, height() / 2);
    viewCenter += QPointF(dx, 0); // Why did you subtract instead of add dx?
    centerOn(viewCenter); // BTW, you don't need to do .x(), .y()
    // You can remove update(); as this is already called in centerOn().
}
```

Please note that if you have, as you said, "`scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)` overrided to `emit horizontalScroll(dx)`", you also have to call the super class method so that the view can scroll itself:

```
void CustomView::scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)
{
    emit horizontalScrolled(dx); // (You should call it different than the slot!)
    QGraphicsView::scrollContentsBy(dx, dy); // <-- This is what I mean!
}
```

Comment: I do already call the superclass method, and when the QScrollBar is hidden they don't initialize, so QScrollBar::setValue results in no behavior. dx is subtracted because when adding dx the scrolls went in the opposite direction.

My view origin is (0,0) in the top left, positive numbers result in a lower position in the view.

Comment: I tried your horizontalScroll() method, it scrolls my view down....and then horizontally in the opposite direction that the emitting view scrolls. changing to viewCenter += QPointF(-1 * dx, 0); sets it in the right direction, but still causes the view to scroll down(I suspect the mapToScene() is causing it).

Comment: Try the following: Remove the point addition line and see what happens when you call `horizontalScroll(anything)` (or see what happens when you call `horizontalScroll(0)`). The problem might be: width() / 2, height() / 2 is an integer division and rounds down if the size is odd. Set the size to even numbers and retry, just as an test. You can also try `(width() + 1) / 2` in order to round up instead of down.